# Pinvoke Bool - MarshalDirectiveExeption

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke

i want to return a struct from the unmanaged code with a bool attribute:

```
EXTERN_C UA_EXPORT_WRAPPER_IMPORT DN_OPstruct DOTNET_GetOperation(){
  DN_OPstruct op;
  op.direction = true;
  return op; }

struct DN_OPstruct{
   bool direction; }
```

My C#-Code looks like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack = 8, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct DN_OPstruct{
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
  bool direction; }

[DllImport("somedll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "somefct",
        ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern DN_OPstruct DOTNET_GetOperation();
```

Unfortunately i get this error message:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occurred in
>   WindowsFormsApplication1 but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, the struct is not p/invoke compatible. Function return values must be blittable and that type is not. The information can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx

> Structures that are returned from platform invoke calls must be blittable types. Platform invoke does not support non-blittable structures as return types.

That same topic goes on to list the types that are blittable, and `bool` is not in the list.

You should use a `byte` instead of `bool`. You can wrap it up like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DN_OPstruct
{
    private byte _direction; 
    public bool direction
    {
        get { return _direction != 0; }
        set { _direction = (byte)(value ? 1 : 0); }
    }
}
```

I would also comment that the use of `Pack` appears to be incorrect here and there is no need for `CharSet` to be specified anywhere.